# Getting list of compatible devices on Android Developer Console

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I used to be able to log into Android Developer console and get a list of all compatible devices for my app. Looks like Google redesigned the developer console and now I can only see the number of devices that my app is compatible with and not the actual models. It used to look like this -
[image]

With the new redesign in place right now, is there any way to still get this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer console interface changes every now and then.

As of now, you can see the model wise device list in **Release management > Device catalog** under **Supported devices** (scroll down).

[image]

Details - [View & restrict your app's compatible devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

You can still see that list following this steps:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I am still not able to see the actual device names, just the number in this screenshot.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.. Try reaching google support as the official FAQ shows this as the only mechanism to manage supported devices  (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en)